Work-energy theorem for time-varying mass system
What I have studied in books is that "Work done by all the forces acting on a body is equal to the change in kinetic energy of the system" as the Work-Energy Theorem says.
But for the derivation, it takes mass $m$ as constant, so if the mass is varying with time, will the law still be valid or not?
As the derivation says $$W_{net} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}{\vec{F}.dx}$$
as $\vec{F}= \frac{\mathrm dP}{\mathrm dt}$ and if $m$ is constant, $\vec{F} = m\vec{a} =m\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}$
$$W_{net} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}{m\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}dx}$$
as $v$ = $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}$
$$W_{net} = m\int_{v_1}^{v_2}{vdv}$$
$$W_{net} = m\left(\frac{v_2^2-v_1^2}{2}\right)$$
$$W_{net} = KE_f - KE_i.$$
But if the mass was variable this derivation wouldn't work. So what can be applied in cases of variable mass system such as rocket propulsion?


But if the mass was variable this derivation wouldn't work. So what
can be applied in cases of variable mass system such as rocket
propulsion?

The work energy theorem does not apply to the rocket propulsion system in space (with no external forces acting on the system). The net work done on the system is zero. The increase in kinetic energy of the system is due to the conversion of chemical potential energy (combustion of the fuel mass) to kinetic energy within the system, not due to the net work done on the system.
The work energy theorem describes a sufficient but not necessary condition for there to be a change in kinetic energy of a system. The following is another example involving elastic potential energy, albeit not with variable mass.
Consider a horizontally oriented spring compressed against a rigid vertical wall held in place by some type of latch. The latch is released and the spring flies off the wall. The wall does no work on (transfers no energy to) the spring. The resulting kinetic energy of the spring comes from the elastic potential energy stored within it while compressed.
Hope this helps.

So Work-Energy Theorem is not but conservation of total energy (if non-conservative forces as exertnal force are absent) will still be applicable when mass is varying, right? But the formula for conservation of energy also came from Work-Energy Theorem (according to my book) so is it?

@ShivamChouhan What book is that. If possible, I'd like to see any statement in context.

@ShivamChouhan the formula for conservation of mechanical energy only comes from the work energy theorem for work involving conservative forces.

@ShivamChouhan On the other hand the work energy theorem applies even when mechanical energy is not conserved, i.e. it applies when there are non conservative forces such as the kinetic friction force

Did I answer your question?

Oh yes, it this solves my question, thank you very much <3

and the book, you asked at page 8, its here https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?keph1=5-7
